# Asynchronous with interrupts

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

I have an asynchronous function that is running in the background. This function polls data through TCP. I have another function `GetClientNameById` which will get the current value and return in `json` format. However, I'm getting **NULL** for all the values. How can I interrupt in the middle, get the values and resume the polling? Below is my code.

```
class Poll
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
}

public async void Polling(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return;
            }

            //TODO

            poll.A = reply1;
            poll.B = reply2;
            poll.C = reply3;
            poll.D = reply4;
            poll.E = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
        }    
    });
}

Poll poll = new Poll();
public string GetClientNameById(string Id)
{
    string json = "";
    if (Id == "Poll")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reply: " + poll.A + " " + poll.B + " " + poll.C + " " + poll.D + " " + poll.E);

        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(poll, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
    }    
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Where is the `poll` variable declared and instantiated?

Comment: And you have verified that the same instance is shared between the `Polling` function and `GetClientNameById`? You have also verified while debugging that your code reaches the place in the `Polling` in which you are setting the 4 properties? And once this code is reached and executed you have verified that inside the `GetClientNameById` those 4 properties are null?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov sry. my bad. I misunderstood your question. `poll` is declared above `GetClientNameById`

Comment: OK, and you have verified that you have called the `Polling` and the `GetClientNameById` functions on the **same instance** of the containing class? Since the `poll` variable is declared as a field of this containing class, each time you create a new instance of it, you will get a different `poll` variable. If you create a new instance of the containing class and invoke `GetClientNameById` on it, then it is obvious that the poll variable will not have its fields initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are calling the `Polling` and `GetClientNameById` functions on different instances of the containing class. Since your `poll` variable is declared as a field of this containing class, then a new instance of it will be created each time.

Make sure that you are calling those functions on the same instance:

```
var myContainingClass = new MyContainingClass();
// Start polling
await myContainingClass.Polling(someCancellationToken);

// Call the GetClientNameById function on the same instance
// on which you called the Polling function
myContainingClass.GetClientNameById("Poll");
myContainingClass.GetClientNameById("Poll");
myContainingClass.GetClientNameById("Poll");
...
```

Also there's a racing condition in your code. Since inside your polling function you have 4 fields being assigned, your `GetClientNameById` function, if called at the same time, might *see* those fields assigned from different invocations of the TCP call. You may consider synchronizing the access to this poll variable using a gateway:

```
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim gateway = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
```

and then when writing the fields acquire a write lock:

```
gateway.EnterWriteLock();
try
{
    poll.A = reply1;
    poll.B = reply2;
    poll.C = reply3;
    poll.D = reply4;
    poll.E = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
}
finally
{
    gateway.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

and when reading:

```
if (Id == "Poll")
{
    gateway.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reply: " + poll.A + " " + poll.B + " " + poll.C + " " + poll.D + " " + poll.E);

        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(poll, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
    }
    finally
    {
        gateway.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use the same instance for both function calls you may consider making the `poll` field static so that it is shared between all instances. The remark about the racing condition still applies though and you need to properly synchronize the access to this field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I did some research and it seems like `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is not recommended for `async-await`. Therefore, I've used `SemaphoreSlim` instead.